# Using loc-args for push notifications is adding parens and line breaks

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have no idea why I'm seeing this behavior.  I'm using loc-key and loc-args in the APNS payload.  When there are no parameters it works fine:

> "Your tech has arrived"

When I populate loc-args, ios is adding line breaks and parenthesis to the notification:

> "Your tech, (
>
> Victor
>
> ), has arrived"

Here's the payload I'm sending:

> {"apns":{"loc-key":"ARRIVED_KEY", "loc-args":["Victor"],"badge":0,"sound":"chime"}

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I hope the problem is in JSON. Try this json..

```
{
        "apns": {
            "loc-key": "ARRIVED_KEY",
            "loc-args": [
                "Victor"
            ],
            "badge": 0,
            "sound": "chime"
        }
    }
```

Comment: This gives the same result. :/